# Wenn während des Schreibens einer Antwort die Frage geschlossen wird

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### Fallbeispiel

Kurz nachdem die Frage [Warum benennen die Deutschen Filmtitel um?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/29853/1487) gepostet wurde, habe ich sie gelesen, und mich entschieden, eine Antwort zu schreiben. Zu diesem Zeitpunkt war die Frage noch offen, es gab aber ein schon ein paar Close-Votes, was ja leider nichts ungewöhnliches ist. (Ich finde, es werden viel zu viele Fragen von den immer gleichen Personen geschlossen, aber das sollte man an anderer Stelle diskutieren.) Da ich fand (und noch immer finde), dass diese Frage on-topic ist, habe ich nicht damit gerechnet, dass sich fünf Frageschließer finden würden, die auch diese Frage schließen würden, aber da habe ich mich geirrt.

Nachdem ich gerne ausführliche Antworten schreibe, und oft auch an Formulierungen länger herumfeile, dauert es in manchen Fällen schon mal eine Stunde bis ich eine Antwort so weit fertig habe, dass ich sie posten möchte. 
Im vorliegenden Fall hat es nicht ganz so lange gedauert, aber doch rund 20 oder 30 Minuten. (Ich habe nicht auf die Uhr geschaut).

Ich hatte die Antwort fast fertig, als plötzlich am oberen Bildschirmrand eine Warnmeldung erschien, in der mir mitgeteilt wurde, dass die Frage nun geschossen ist, und keine Antworten mehr akzeptiert werden. Ich habe dennoch meine Antwort fertig formuliert, und dann auf »Post your Answer« geklickt (der Button war ja nach wie vor vorhanden). Allerdings wurde meine Antwort tatsächlich nicht mehr akzeptiert. Meine Arbeit war also völlig umsonst.

### Frage

Kann man es bitte so einrichten, dass Antworten, an denen schon geschrieben wird, auch dann noch akzeptiert werden, wenn die Frage währenddessen auf »on hold« gesetzt wird?

Immerhin liegen dem System ja die automatisch erstellten Zwischenspeicherstände der Antwort vor, so dass bekannt ist, dass es Antworten im Zustand der Erfassung gibt. Wenn also eine Antwort fertiggestellt und gepostet wird, und sie eine erst kürzlich geschlossene Frage betrifft, dann soll bitte geprüft werden, ob es für diese Frage Sicherungsstände gibt, die erstellt wurden, bevor die Frage geschlossen wurde. In so einem Fall handelt es sich dann um eine Antwort, die begonnen wurde, als die Frage noch offen war, und ich finde, dass solche Antworten akzeptiert werden sollten.

Comment: Dass das bei dir so war wundert mich. Mir sind bisher immer nur Antworten aufgefallen, die teilweise mehrere Stunden nach Fragenschließung noch abgeschickt wurden … Aber vielleicht hat SE in den letzten zwei Wochen ein Update gemacht …

Comment: Ist mir auch schon passiert und hat mich geärgert wie Bolle, aber das System ist vernünftig so und Du solltest eigentlich wissen, dass das keine Frage spezifisch für German-Meta ist, und sie im General Meta stellen.

Answer (score 7):

Anders als User mit weniger Reputationspunkten kannst Du die Close Votes sehen, die ein Post hat:

> Zu diesem Zeitpunkt war die Frage noch offen, es gab aber ein schon ein paar Close-Votes, was ja leider nichts ungewöhnliches ist.

Falls Du mit den genannten Schließgründen nicht einverstanden bist, und die gestellte Frage beantworten möchtest, solltest Du Dich hier aktiv einbringen.

**Ein kurzer Kommentar, weshalb Du die Frage für gut hältst, und ein Upvote auf die Frage hilft vielleicht, das Schließen zu verhindern.**

Wenn Du erwähnst, dass Du gerade an einer längeren Antwort bastelst, werden hoffentlich die meisten von uns mit dem 5. Close Vote noch warten, bis Deine Antwort veröffentlicht wurde.

Wenn aber das Kind in den Brunnen gefallen ist, und eine Frage geschlossen wurde, bevor Deine Antwort fertig ist, hilft es tatsächlich nur zu warten, bis sie wieder geöffnet wird und das kann dauern. Du solltest also einen eventuell schon geschriebenen Text irgendwo lokal auf Deinem Computer zwischenspeichern. Es kann auch helfen, einen Moderator mit einer Flagge auf die Problematik hinzuweisen und ihn bitten, die Frage noch einmal für Dich zu öffnen, damit Du Deine Antwort loswerden kannst.

**Ganz im Allgemeinen möchten wir aber nicht, dass Fragen, die *off topic* sind, beantwortet werden.**

Nicht beantwortete, geschlossene Fragen werden nach einer gewissen Zeit automatisch entfernt. Es wird aber ungleich schwerer, beantwortete Fragen & Antworten zu löschen. Ganz besonders widersprüchlich ist es, wenn jemand mit seinem Vote eine Frage als *off topic* oder *unklar* in die Queue schickt, aber dennoch selbst eine Antwort schreibt. Die Leute werden dadurch ermutigt auch einmal eine *off topic* Frage zu stellen, wenn sie sehen, dass man immer auch eine Antwort erhält. Schon deshalb darf es nicht sein, dass eine begonnene Antwort automatisch die Close Votes der anderen Benutzer überstimmt.

Answer (score -2):

Schon wieder!

Soeben habe ich eine Antwort auf diese Frage geschrieben: [Pronomen "es" oder "er"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30666/1487)

Ich habe die Antwort fertig, lese sie nocheinmal durch, und während des Durchlesens poppt am oberen Bildschirmrand ein oranger Balken auf, der mir mitteilt, dass die Frage nun geschlossen ist. Ich kann tatsächlich meine Antwort nicht mehr posten.

Weil ich hoffe, dass ein Moderator vielleicht doch noch meine Antwort einbringen kann, poste ich sie hier:

---

The sentence is correct. This is, because German has another gender system than English.

In English only persons or things that are somehow personlike (like pets, android robots and sometimes even ships), can be male or female. Everything that is not personoid is always neuter in english.

This is not true in German. Things (to be more precise: words for things) can have any of the three genders. A knife (das Messer) is neuter, a fork (die Gabel) is female and a spoon (der Löffel) is male. But as said before: Not the things carry the gender, the word are the things that have a gender.

There are things, that have more than one name. You call this synonyms. For example, the word "car" can be translated as »das Auto« (neuter), »der Wagen« (male) or »die Karre« (female) ("Karre" is a shabby car). You can use all three words for the same thing. You could also replace "der Motor" in your example by "die Maschine" (the engine) which is female. The you would say:

> Die Maschine des Autos hat viel zu wenig Öl. Infolgedessen ist **sie** kaputt gegangen.

Also mention, that the biological gender of a person does not always match with the grammatical gender of the word that is used for this Person. Most famous example: The girl is »das Mädchen« in German, which is not female but neuter. Same for »das Weib« ("Weib" is an old and pejorative word for "woman").

> Das Mädchen ist hübsch. **Es** hat lange Beine.
>   Dieses Weib ist schrecklich. **Es** macht alles kaputt.

But fut this case (non-female grammatical Gender for biological female person) there is a relatively young exception. You can also use female pronouns:

> Das Mädchen ist hübsch. **Sie** hat lange Beine.
>   Dieses Weib ist schrecklich. **Sie** macht alles kaputt.

The word »Motor« is male. For this reason, in a dictionary you will either find "(m)" for "male", or the male article "der" ("der Motor"). And since the motor is male in German, you have to use a male pronoun when referring to *him*.

Comment: Aus Takkats Antwort: »Ganz im Allgemeinen möchten wir aber nicht, dass Fragen, die off topic sind, beantwortet werden.«

Comment: @Jan: Die Frage hat zwei Downvotes und ebenso zwei Upvotes. Also halten sie mindestens drei Leute (der Autor und die beiden Upvoter) für wichtig, gut oder interessant. Die Entscheidung, die Frage wäre off topic, beruht auch nicht auf objektiven Kriterien, sondern auf der subjektiven Meinung von fünf Leuten. Darüberhinaus kann man auch darüber diskutieren, ob das angeführte Off-Topic-Kriterium, nämlich den Verweis auf eine generelle Referenz, überhaupt zielführend ist. Insofern bin ich ausdrücklich nicht Takkats zitierter Meinung.

Comment: @Takkat (Fortsetzung des vorherigen Kommentars): Ich habe auch in beiden Fällen keine geschlossenen Fragen beantwortet! Beide Fragen waren offen, als ich meine Antwort schrieb. Sie wurden aber geschlossen bevor ich mit dem Schreiben meiner Antwort fertig werden konnte. Diesen Umstand kritisiere ich. Wenn ich mal begonnen habe, eine offene Frage zu beantworten, möchte ich meine Antwort auch dann noch posten können, wenn die Frage geschlossen wird bevor ich mit dem Schreiben der Antwort fertig werde. Darum geht es.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Du kannst in solchen Fällen, und wenn Du siehst, dass eine Frage schon mehrere Close Votes hat, ja schon mal mit einer Antwort anfangen, die Du aber erst später fertig schreibst (über ein Edit).

Comment: @Takkat: Als ich die Frage begonnen habe, hatte sie höchstens 2 Close Votes. Aber ich habe für meine Antwort geschätzte 30 Minuten benötigt, und als ich die fix fertige Antwort nur noch korrekturgelesen habe, poppte plötzlich die Sperrmeldung auf. Das finde ich nicht ok. Es ist in Ordnung, wenn man nach dem Sperren einer Frage nicht mehr mit dem Erfassen einer neuen Antwort beginnen darf. Aber wenn ich schon eine halbe Stunde an der Antwort herumfeile, und am Server schon automatische Sicherungen meiner Antwort gespeichert sind, dann möchte ich meine Antwort auch veröffentlichen dürfen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: die Frage hatte **4 Stunden** lang bereits 4 Close Votes bevor sie dann mit dem 5. Vote geschlossen wurde, das ist nicht wirklich "plötzlich".